# egrep doesn't work as expected on SunOS system

Tags: rhel, regular-expression, solaris, gnu

Here is what I want to achieve on SunOS:

Only pattern like `[text_text=text]`, `[text=text]`, `[text]` or `text` are valid patterns, where by `text` I mean anything in `0-9,a-z,A-Z, space, newline, tab, enter`. Anything other than this is invalid pattern. i.e `egrep -v` should capture it. Patterns like `[[[text]`, `[text]]]`, `[text`, `text]` should also be invalid

I used the below on Linux box (RHEL) and it works perfectly fine:

```
egrep -v "^[ ]*([a-zA-Z0-9\t\n\v\f\r ]*|\[{1}[_a-zA-Z0-9\t\n\v\f\r ]*(=[a-zA-Z0-9\t\n\v\f\r ]*)?\]{1})[ ]*$" file1
```

File1:

```
[FEATURE_ID=2]
[FEATURE_REV=1]
[NO_OF_BYTES=18]
001203658080400160b9d0ae45000080
[CRC]
c068
```

On RHEL BOX the `egrep -v` statement above don't give any output as expected

How can I achieve this in Solaris, as the same doesn't work and gives an output:

```
[FEATURE_ID=2]
[FEATURE_REV=1]
[NO_OF_BYTES=18]
[CRC]
```

Comment: Please provide a sample output from the Solaris server, using the same command, run against the same sample file you provided.

Comment: @MelBurslan Please see at the last of my post the sample ouptut I got on Sloaris box is already provided for same file1

Comment: Which `egrep` is being used here? I suspect you may want to try `/usr/xpg4/bin/egrep` rather than `/usr/bin/egrep`

Comment: @forquare Thanks for your comments. I've mentioned only `egrep` in my script without any absolute pathname. when i do `which egrep` on my Solaris box it says `/usr/bin/egrep`. Can you please explain how `usr/xpg4/bin/egrep` is different ?

Comment: @dig_123 the utilities under `/usr/xpg4` are POSIX compliant. See `man egrep` for further explanation (same man page for both versions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the case on Solaris, `/usr/bin/egrep` is a legacy implementation that isn't POSIX-compliant, while `/usr/xpg4/bin/egrep` is a POSIX-compliant implementation and has little if anything beyond POSIX. Unless you're running legacy Solaris applications from the pre-POSIX days, make sure that **`/usr/xpg4/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH`**.

GNU tools (which you're used to on Linux) often have many features beyond what POSIX mandates. If you need portability, stick to POSIX. POSIX doesn't define `egrep`; it's a widespread synonym of [`grep -E`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html), i.e. `grep` with [extended regular expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) syntax.

Solaris's `/usr/bin/egrep` doesn't support `{…}` occurrence counts. You're only using `{1}` here which has no effect, so just drop it.

Neither implementation of `egrep` or `grep -E` on Solaris supports backslash escapes for control characters. That's a GNU extension. POSIX leaves backlash-letter undefined. Use the `[:space:]` class instead of `\t\n\v\f\r`.

```
LC_CTYPE=C grep -Ev '^[ ]*([[:alnum:][:space:]]*|\[[_[:alnum:][:space:]]*(=[[:alnum:][:space:]]*)?\])[ ]*$' file1
```

Comment: Might be worth adding that some GNU variants can be found under `/usr/sfw`, though I'm not 100% sure if `egrep` is one of them.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for detailed explanation on the issue and workaround.